# Grails beans in resources.groovy not injected into service

Tags: grails, dependency-injection

Using Grails 3.2.3/3.2.6, I have an issue that certains beans configured in Resources.groovy are not injected into the services also defined in this file.
In real life, one of these configured services is the mail that is swapped by a test mail service in test environment and the other is the executor service to make sure that async processes are done synchronously in test mode. The email being an async process, it uses the other service.

[Here is a sample project](https://github.com/edarchis/grails-config)

I have a controller OneController:

```
class OneController {
    def theService
    def theOtherService

    def index() {
        render status:200, text: theService.getDataFromOtherService()
    }

    def direct() {
        render status:200, text: theOtherService.klet()
    }
}
```

The resources.groovy file defines the mapping for those `def`:

```
beans = {
    theService(OneService)
    theOtherService(AlternateSecondService)
}
```

---

The services are pretty straightforward:

```
class OneService {
    def theOtherService

    def getDataFromOtherService() {
        theOtherService.klet()
    }
}
```

and

```
class AlternateSecondService {

    def klet() {
        "Mariette"
    }
}
```

---

Now, if I access `http://localhost:8080/one/index`, I get a null pointer exception on `theOtherService.klet()` because `theOtherService` is null.

If I access `http://localhost:8080/one/direct`, the controller does have the bean properly injected and works fine.

I currently avoided the issue by using `Holders.getGrailsApplication().mainContext.theOtherService.klet()` but I'd like to avoid using global variables...

Why is the first service not injected the second one ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your `theService` bean is not being subjected to auto wiring.  There is more than 1 way to make that happen.  You could use the Spring annotation or you could do something like this in `resources.groovy`:

```
beans = {
    theService(OneService) { bean ->
        bean.autowire = 'byName'
    }
    theOtherService(AlternateSecondService)
}
```